# Python and Matlab Power to the matrix show different output for same matrix

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting an algorithm written in matlab to python. I have fitness(sum(x.^2)) function which apply power of 2 to matrix and sum the result. But generating same function in python result is too big. Below is the piece of code for matlab and python. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

**Matlab code:**

```
  x =[-39.77402526 -56.2758048   -8.7928885  -62.55202915 43.51141373; 
       -81.80734056  -9.25633467   
        9.59188435 -12.89390549 50.78066165;
       -54.90330694 -47.32537425   2.43481477 -65.93824603 44.37150669;
       -80.98320005 -10.15506252   9.21819093 -13.80578393 50.64317438];

%apply oiwer and sum the result column wise 
result =sum(x.^2)
```

Result is in this format:

```
1.0e+04 *

1.784706585816911 ,0.559546228009842 , 0.026022250054335,  
0.861746110900216, 0.900548043961882
```

**Python code:**

```
x=np.array([[-39.77402526, -56.2758048 ,  -8.7928885 , -62.55202915,
         43.51141373],
       [-81.80734056,  -9.25633467,   9.59188435, -12.89390549,
         50.78066165],
       [-54.90330694, -47.32537425,   2.43481477, -65.93824603,
         44.37150669],
       [-80.98320005, -10.15506252,   9.21819093, -13.80578393,
         50.64317438]])

result = np.sum(np.power(x,2),1)
print(result)
```

Result is:

```
array([17847.06585817,  5595.4622801 ,   260.22250054,  8617.461109  ,9005.48043962])
```

Comment: The Python output you provide is not [what your Python code produces](https://tio.run/##VZDPbsIwDIfvfYocW6m1/DexDzwJ4sABaZNGqUrR4Om7dGgT5BLZ@eXTZ0@P5eMyyrp@nqfLvKTxdp4e6XhN49Tcd@MEx3k@Ptr9fpCAUhTZOPdpsAxczFE99SkNDiXY3a1WQ2YwY@Qg65v0d1TAiJSkyOG/vR@cwLGIouUNFMCWRTSXWqUAC3JXsYolBg8JNI0XrCEUx5wp2yvWFAJFMIfWr1pA2KQo24ZlUFEnLWWzNQhx1ozyaqsghayC480WIVwYEX@NEMhqpu7kacvkFBiyvUmdy4pLyLttVqGi4odD18yn6@1rSbu6bbjezm29psv3aW7vPXc9dc00f45L@4x16/oD)

Comment: yes sorry...this is example, I just want to show difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Matlab code `result = sum(x.^2)` you are applying the `sum` function to a matrix that has more than one row. This computes the sum along the first axis, that is, vertically.

In Python / Numpy, **the first axis has index 0, not 1**. So, you should use

```
result = np.sum(np.power(x,2), 0)
```

As an additional note, in Matlab it's safer to provide a **second input to `sum`** to specify the axis you want to sum along:

```
result = sum(x.^2, 1);
```

This way the sum will always be along the first axis, even if `x` happens to be row vector.

You may also be confused by the way Matlab displays the result, using **scientific notation**. Note that the multiplier `1.0e+04 *` affects all displayed entries.